# pyspark2 - saveasTextFile not giving clean csv

Tags: csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark2 on a Cloudera Hadoop cluster on AWS.  Spark version is 2.0.0.cloudera1, Python version = Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.|

My goal is to extract a subset of data from hdfs, and then create a flat .csv file of the results.  But what I am getting is a csv file that has "field_name=" prepended to each value.  How do get a regular .csv when using rdd.saveasTextFile?

My code looks like this, after reading in the source from HDFS:

```
outp = src_file.select(pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime("report_epoch"),"field01","field02","field03","field04","field05")

outp.rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(path=source_dir_path, compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
```

and the resulting file (after uncompressing) looks like this:

```
Row(fromunixtime(report_epoch,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)=u'2017-02-01 00:00:00', field01=u'23ad61e1f771', field02=u'GG3', field03=27245805, field04=316260105, field05=150)
Row(fromunixtime(report_epoch,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)=u'2017-02-01 00:00:00', field01=u'925aa5c25a49', field02=u'KLK767', field03=1133298142, field04=1366285744, field05=150)
Row(fromunixtime(report_epoch,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)=u'2017-02-01 00:00:00', field01=u'8317d1cb65001', field02=u'HH721S', field03=234439515, field04=18147477579, field05=150)
```

This is the data I'm looking for but I want it in a traditional, flat .csv format that would look like:

```
2017-02-01 00:00:00,'23ad61e1f771','GG3',27245805,316260105,150
2017-02-01 00:00:00,'925aa5c25a49','KLK767',1133298142,1366285744,150
2017-02-01 00:00:00,'8317d1cb65001','HH721S',234439515,18147477579,150
```

So how do I tell saveasTextFile to make me a file my way?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest the following:

```
df = your dataframe object
df.coalesce(1).write.csv('name_of_outputfolder',header=True)
```

That should do the trick.
Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks PAco, but I'm getting an error with that:   outp.coalesce(1).write.csv("cc_out.csv", sep='|', header=True)
AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'csv'

Comment: MY googling says that  df.write.csv() is standard as part of Spark 2.0 so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  I agree with you, Paco.  This should work.